# WildFly init.d scripts for SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, wildfly, suse, init.d

I want to start and stop WildFly 15 on Linux SUSE 11 together with the machine. I'm not expert in Linux and this is my first experience with SUSE. I found WildFly comes with init.d scripts for 2 Linux distributions: Debian and Red Hat.

- docs/contrib/scripts/init.d/wildfly-init-debian.sh
- docs/contrib/scripts/init.d/wildfly-init-redhat.sh

I found that in older versions of JBoss there was a SUSE script (jboss_init_suse.sh).

Why is not there a SUSE script in newer WildFly releases? Is there an easy way to create them from the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

SUSE uses `systemd`.  Use the scripts and in `docs/contrib/scripts/systemd` to get started.  The `README` goes into details.  Newer Ubuntu and Debian environments also use `systemd`.

And as it has bit me multiple times - do not forget the very last line in the README - it enables it for reboot.  I tend to start Wildfly and then forget to enable the service and on the first reboot I wonder what happened.

Comment: Thanks! The info is great, but I found out systemd was included in SUSE 12 and I'm having SUSE 11, so it is still using init.d folder :( I updated the question to specify that it is version 11

Comment: Sorry - SUSE still confuses me a bit.  According to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) openSUSE has had systemd since March of 2011.  SUSE Linux Enterprise since October of 2014.  That one does say v12.  I guess you're on SLES v11.